Failed to fill the white area
I once asked the the question, and Qrrbrbirlbel suggested I use the library spath3. Now I want to draw a new graph. I plan to mimic it, but it seems to have failed. There must be an issue with my code, but I haven't figured out what it is yet.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    
    \tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,inner sep=2pt},
        blackedge/.style={thick}
    }
    
    
    \fill[gray!20] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    %\fill[white] (-2,0) -- (0.2,-2.1) -- (2.1,-0.1) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
    
    % Define the vertices
    \node[vertex] (s) at (0,2) {$s$};
    \node[vertex] (t) at (0,-2) {$t$};
    \node at (-1.5, 0) {$\alpha_1$}; 
    \node at (1.7, -0.2) {$\alpha_2$}; 
    
    \node[vertex] (lef) at (-2.5,0.5) {};
    \node[vertex] (x) at (-2.5,-0.5) {$x$};
    
    \node[vertex] (y2) at (2.5,-0.5) {};
    \draw (s) -- (x)[spath/save=sx];
    \draw (s) -- (y2)[spath/save=sy2];
    \draw (lef) -- (t)[spath/save=left];
    %\draw (t) -- (y1);
    \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(t.10) (2.5,0.5)  (0,2.6)  (-2.7, 0.7)  (x.120)}[spath/save=tx];
  
 
  \scoped[
 spath/split at intersections={tx}{sy2},
  spath/remove components={tx}{2},
  spath/remove components={sy2}{2}] 
\fill[white]
  (t) [spath/use={tx}]
  -- (spath cs:{tx} 1) [spath/use={sy2, reverse, weld}]
--(s) --(-2,0)--(t)
 -- cycle;

    \node at (0,0) {$\mathcal{N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The one on the right is what I want.

I want to ask how I should handle the white area?


With
\draw green [spath/use={tx}]
-- (spath cs:{tx} 1);



change in
\draw [green](t) [spath/use={tx}]
    -- (spath cs:{tx} 0);


For the rest by putting .center on the nodes and the library backgrounds

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, spath3,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    
    \tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,inner sep=2pt},
        blackedge/.style={thick}
    }
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer={color=gray!20}]
      \fill (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \end{scope}

    
    
    % Define the vertices
    \node[vertex] (s) at (0,2) {$s$};
    \node[vertex] (t) at (0,-2) {$t$};
    \node at (-1.5, 0) {$\alpha_1$}; 
    \node at (1.7, -0.2) {$\alpha_2$}; 
    
    \node[vertex] (lef) at (-2.5,0.5) {};
    \node[vertex] (x) at (-2.5,-0.5) {$x$};
    
    \node[vertex] (y2) at (2.5,-0.5) {};
    \draw (s) -- (x)[spath/save=sx];
    \draw (s) -- (y2)[spath/save=sy2];
    \draw (lef) -- (t)[spath/save=left];
    %\draw (t) -- (y1);
    \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(t.10) (2.5,0.5)  (0,2.6)  (-2.7, 0.7)  (x.120)}[spath/save=tx];
  

  \scoped[
    on background layer,
    spath/split at intersections={tx}{sy2},
    spath/remove components={tx}{2},
    spath/remove components={sy2}{2}
  ] 
\fill[white]
  (t) [spath/use={tx}]
  -- (spath cs:{tx} 0) [spath/use={sy2, weld}]
--(s.center)%<<  .center 
--(-2,0)
--(t.center)%<<< 
-- cycle
;
% \draw [green](t) [spath/use={tx}]
% -- (spath cs:{tx} 1);


    \node at (0,0) {$\mathcal{N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Nice. That's great! Recently, I've been using a lot of background elements like the above codes, including \fill, in my paper, and I've noticed a significant slowdown in compilation time. May you have any better suggestions?  Of course, that's a separate topic. For example, regarding the figure above, are there any improvements that could be made to help increase compilation speed?

You can compile once with the standalone class, then integrate the figure with \includegraphics.
